# Size of a struct with union and bitfields

Tags: c, struct, sizeof, memory-alignment, bit-fields

I'm trying to count the size in bytes of this struct and have a couple of questions

```
struct stc {
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
    union stc2 {
        long a0;
        int a1;
        int a2;
    };
    char arr[10];
    int z:2;
};
```

I'm checking the size in this way:

```
int main(void) {
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(struct stc));
}
```

and compile with:

`gcc -std=c99 -m32 -Wall -Wextra test.c`

It's gcc 4.9 and I'm on 64-bit computer but first want to try with 32-bit values so -m32. Now, the result is `20`, but I've no idea why is that. This is how I'm counting.

```
struct stc {     
    int a;        // +4 = 4
    int b;        // +4 = 8
    char c;       // +1 but next is long, so +4 (alignment) = 12
    union stc2 {
        long a0;  // +4 = 16
        int a1;
        int a2;
    };
    char arr[10]; // +8 (for arr[8]) and 2 bits left = 24 (or 28)
    int z:2;      // +4 = 28 (or 32) 
                  // I'm not sure how it'll work with 2 bits left from char array and
                  // 2 bits from int, so that why I count 2 different values. 
};
```

This was strange so I tried to figure this out and I know that this union seem to be size 0.

```
struct stc {
    union stc2 {
        long a0;
        int a1;
        int a2;
    };
```

`sizeof(struct stc) == 0`. I think that is because of compiler optimization? If so, how to turn it off? If not, why is that? 
Another question is of course how to count the size of this struct properly (with or without optimization) and why the size of this simple struct:

```
struct stc {
    char arr[10];
};
```

is 10 not a 12. I've thought that every value is aligned to 4,8,12,16,20 etc if you won't say to compiler to not align values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you have a lot of questions in here. I'll answer some as I go:

#### sizeof struct is zero?

You gave the code:

```
struct stc {
    union stc2 {
        long a0;
        int a1;
        int a2;
    };
};
```

Note that you declared no variables inside the struct. You probably meant to do the following, which will likely have the same size as `sizeof(long)`.

```
struct stc {
    union stc2 {
        long a0;
        int a1;
        int a2;
    } x;
};
```

#### Bitfield layouts

So, let's try to figure out where `20` comes from. First, let's rerwite the type without the `union` that isn't doing anything (see previous heading).

Also, note that structs with bitfields are **not required** to be laid out in memory the same way as normal types. But let's make some guesses anyways.

```
struct stc {
    int a;        // Offset 0,  Size 4
    int b;        // Offset 4,  Size 4
    char c;       // Offset 8,  Size 1
    char arr[10]; // Offset 9,  Size 10
    int z:2;      // Offset 19, Size 1-ish
};
```

So it seems to fit fine.

#### sizeof wasn't rounded up to 12?

```
struct stc {
    char arr[10];
};
```

So, each type has a size and an alignment requirement. For `char`, both of these are 1. For `uint32_t`, they are usually both 4. But depending on the architecture, the alignment could be different.

So in this case, the maximum alignment needs of any element of the struct `stc` is 1. So the alignment requirements of the entire struct is still `1`, even though the size is `10`.

Generally speaking, you want to add whatever padding is necessary to the size such that the declaration `struct stc x[2]` would cause all of the elements to be properly aligned.

#### Recommendations

So, there are a few things that you could do here to help learn what your compiler is doing.

1. When posting questions about memory layout on stack overflow, it's very helpful to use the types defined in `stdint.h`. These include types like `int32_t` and `int16_t`. These are nicer because there is no confusion on what size a `long` is.
2. You can use the offsetof tool to determine where a compiler is placing the members. You can learn some more about how to use it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof).

#### Padding can occur though:

Here's a pretty simple example of a struct with a good bit of padding that the compiler would have to insert.

```
struct x {
    uint64_t x; // Offset 0,  Size 8
    char     y; // Offset 8,  Size 1
                // Offset 9,  Size 1 (Padding)
    uint16_t z; // Offset 10, Size 2
                // Offset 12, Size 4 (Padding)
};
```

Comment: That's the perfect answer. Thank you for your help, now I understand this better :)

Comment: Sorry for bothering again, but actually I'd like to know more about how bitfields can be laid out in memory. I though I would figure this out for myself with offset tool but it gives me an error `error: attempt to take address of bit-field structure member`.

Comment: Two things. One: you can't take the address of a bitfield because it could be laid out in memory on a non-byte boundary. Secondly, the language designers placed no restrictions on how a bitfield will be laid out in memory, so you would need to look at your compiler documentation.